# can I use C# IDisposable to automate job when exit the scope?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Can I use IDisposable to do automate job when triggers in exiting the scope?
This case, I am using IDisposable to only do some job in the end of method, not 'disposing' resources.
This is one of my code :

```
public class ScopeTimer : IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private string _logMessage;

    public ScopeTimer(string logMessage = "")
    {
        sw.Start();
        _logMessage = logMessage;
    }

    public void SetMessage(string logMessage)
    {
        _logMessage = logMessage;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Logging.Logger.Log($"[{_logMessage}] takes {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
    }
}
```

and I am using like this :

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    using var timer = new ScopeTimer();

    // do some job
    // when method finished, timer.Dispose() is called
}
```

At least now, this code looks working fine, but is this a safe way in other many circumstances?

Comment: Huh, define "safe".

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Can I assume IDisposable.Dispose() will be called  everytime when exactly the end of the scope?

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. Having a `using` statement guarantees that `Dispose` is called at the end of the scope. They are called in the reverse order of their definition if there are multiple using statements. Even `using null` is valid in case that your cleanup stuff depends on some conditions.

Comment: `using` turns into `try`/`finally`. The `finally` statement is _guaranteed_ to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Even [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) does it in [Nito.AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) like:

```
SemaphoreSlim _syncRoot = new();

...

using var lockHandle = this._syncRoot.Lock();
// or async
using var lockHandle = await this._syncRoot.LockAsync();
```

But this is opinion based. In my opinion it helps to make code cleaner because you can setup and restore a state and both parts are next to each other. It's easy to see that you don't miss something.

The drawback is that you might create some instances that needs to be freed. That might create some pressure for the GC.

We created a struct (not a class) to wrap such cleanup code:

```
public readonly struct Finally : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action? _onDispose;

    public Finally(Action onDispose)
    {
        _ = onDispose ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(onDispose));

        this._onDispose = onDispose;
    }

    public static Finally Create(Action onDispose)
    {
        return new Finally(onDispose);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Keep in mind that a struct can always be created using new() or default and
        // in that cases _onDispose is null!
        this._onDispose?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

You can use this like:

```
this._childControl.BeginUpdate();
using var @finally = Finally.Create(this._childControl.EndUpdate);

// or
this._member.SomeEvent -= this.OnMemberSomeEvent;
using var @finally = Finally.Create(() => this._member.SomeEvent += this.OnMemberSomeEvent);
```

Yes the memory allocation for the `Finally`-struct is unnecessary and the second example creates a delegate. All that stuff needs time and memory. In applications where performance is a real issue it might be better to use the normal `try...finally` blocks.

But we're also using *Linq* and this does also need context objects and delegates and nobody cares.

In my opinion, obvious correctness is more important than performance, because a quick but wrong result doesn't help anyone.